# Upload File on selenium node (grid environment) , where in upload button is not of input(type='file')

Tags: file-upload, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I do have a page , where import button looks like this .

[image: import_button]

Dom Structure of above import button is as below

```
<button ngf-select="" ng-model="$parent.enduserMashups.files" class="btn btn-default text-center ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
    <i class="icon-import-data"></i>
    <span>Import</span></button>
```

I have written selenium upload utility as below , which works fine in case of NON-GRID environment (local machine)

```
public void uploadFile(String filePath)
    {
    // Setting up clipBoard location
    StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(filePath);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);

    // Using Robot class to upload file
    Robot robot;
    try
    {
        robot = new Robot();
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Press Enter
         robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

        // Release Enter
         robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

          // Press CTRL+V
         robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
         robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);

        // Release CTRL+V
         robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
         robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
         try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            };

        // Press Enter 
         robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
         robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);


    } catch (AWTException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

In case of running above code on selenium grid-node environment , 'import' button gets clicked on node browser instance and here it doesn't find file(obviously), as it is saved on another machine from where testcase is running . 
Googling a lot , I found some solutions which states that in case of having  button , we can use webdriver.sendKeys(file) method , which sends file to selenium node directly , however that is applicable in case of  tag only .

What about in case of NOT having  element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can do to solve your issue.

1. You need to build a custom servlet which has a POST/GET method defined and which can be used to trigger a file upload. ( See [here](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/07/java-servlet-file-upload-using-commons-fileupload/) for an example). You need to also make sure that this servlet will return back the absolute file path of where the file was saved after it was accepted.
2. You now inject the newly built custom servlet into the Grid node ( See [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp#customizing-the-grid) to learn how to do it )
3. Similar to (1) and (2) you build another servlet with a GET/POST action which when invoked can internally call your uploadFile() method. [ You will basically pass the filepath that you obtain from invoking the servlet explained in (1)
4. You refer to [this](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2016/01/15/where-did-my-test-run/) blog post of mine to learn how to find out where did the Grid route your tests to and using the mechanism I have explained you retrieve the IP and port of the node to which your test was routed to.
5. Using the IP and Port number obtained from (4) you first invoke the Upload file servlet to first upload your file to the remote machine on which the node is running and get back the saved file's absolute file path from the servlet.
6. You now invoke your other servlet which contains the uploadFile() method and driven by the ROBOT APIs by passing the absolute file path from (5) and have it perform the upload action using ROBOT on the remote host.

That should do the trick.

Comment: This sounds an interesting . I will surely give it a try and will let you know . Thanks for an answer , appreciate your suggestion

Comment: @sjethvani - If you found the answer helpful, it would be great if you could please help accept it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer .  I actually used this git project to achieve my task (https://github.com/sterodium/selenium-grid-extensions) . It uses the same approach of creating servlets , registering them on Hub and Node and uploading file through HTTP Post .

Comment: I tried your solution of registering 2 servlets (1 for sending file and 1 for having ROBOT code under it ) . Sending file worked fine , it created temp directory on selenium node and copy pasted file from HUB to Node . However 2nd servlet, which contains ROBOT code is not working . Any idea on why is this so ?

Comment: If your ROBOT code works fine locally then there is no reason why it wouldn't work fine in a remote mode via a call to the servlet because its still the same code that is being invoked in a different way (via a GET/POST Http Call). Have you tried watching the node window to see what is happening ? Have you added any logs etc to the servlet ? What error do you see.. There's a lot of info which we don't know yet. You would need to share that info.

Comment: Yes @Krishnan , i have been investigating this problem sine yesterday & found out from logs that servlet containing ROBOT utility wasn't deployed properly on node . I fixed that & now ROBOT code gets called and file gets selected in file upload window . The only problem I am facing now is in case of PARALLEL test execution . In case of parallel execution , ROBOT handling is not working properly , it selects any window that is active and perform action on that window rather than actual file upload window .  Do u know how to deal with that ?

Comment: That's the only constraint. You cannot run tests in parallel on this node because it would start affecting Robot triggered keyboard and mouse events. The alternative to this is to leverage a docker image wherein you do the same thing. Since containers are light weight you can run more than one node on the same machine.

Comment: I see . Let me then search for docker documentations for implementing this stuff . Moreover it seems implementing docker in our existing selenium grid , will fasten executions , as going through basic docs of docker suggests that we can use same hardware resources to spawn multiple application copies .....  Thanks for your kind suggestions @Krishnan